# uwsgi ImportError: No module named os

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-server

I'm teaching myself how to setup an Ubuntu Server to run my Django application. I want to use Nginx + uwsgi. I know that this question can be very easy for experts but I've spent 6 days looking for it over the internet without getting it (in any case, forgive me if there is any link with the answer). I've followed a lot of tutorials and posts but I didn't found a solution.

I describe my file structure below:

My django project is located in /usr/local/projects/myproject

My virtualenv is in /root/.virtualenvs/myproject

My uwsgi config file myproject.ini is in /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/ and correctly symbolic linked in /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/

```
[uwsgi]

plugins = python 
socket  = /tmp/myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 644
uid     = www-data
gid     = www-data
master  = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 2
no-site=true 

virtualenv = /root/.virtualenvs/myproject
chdir   = /usr/local/projects/myproject
module  = myproject.wsgi:application
pidfile = /usr/local/projects/myproject/myproject.pid
logto   = /var/log/uwsgi/myproject_uwsgi.log  
vacuum  = true
```

My nginx config file myproject.conf is in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and correctly symbolic linked in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/myproject.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name dev.myproject.com www.dev.myproject.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myproject_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myproject_error.log;

    location / { 
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/myproject.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT myproject.wsgi;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /usr/local/projects/myproject/media/;
    }

    location  /static/ {
        alias  /usr/local/projects/myproject/static/;
    }
}
```

When I try to access to dev.myproject.com I get an Internal Server Error. Then I take a look to my uwsgi log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myproject/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
Sat Jul 26 17:39:16 2014 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Sat Jul 26 17:39:16 2014 - --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8559|app: -1|req: -1/8] 79.148.138.10 () {40 vars in 685 bytes} [Sat Jul 26 17:39:16 2014] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 1 headers in 57 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

I need your help because I'm not able to find a solution despite the posibility of being very simple.

If you need to know something else let me know and I will update my question as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you use virtaulenv to create a virtual environment /usr/local/projects/myproject? I see you have something in /root -- my suggestion is that you don't use /root for development since processes can't access the content unless they are running as root. Typically you would want to create a user on your server for a development project and place your source files inside, like /home/myproject/... etc.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution.

I followed kchan's suggestion about not putting any of the contents in the /root/ directory. Basically, I did some small changes in my myproject.conf file and my myproject.ini file. I created a user and structured everything like below:

uwsgi config file myproject.ini in /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/ and correctly symbolic linked in /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/

```
[uwsgi]

plugins = python 
socket  = /tmp/myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 644
uid     = www-data
gid     = www-data
master  = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 2

virtualenv = /home/user/.virtualenvs/myproject
chdir      = /home/user/projects/myproject
module     = myproject.wsgi:application
pidfile    = /home/user/projects/myproject/myproject.pid
daemonize  = /var/log/uwsgi/myproject_uwsgi.log  
vacuum     = true
```

nginx config file myproject.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and correctly symbolic linked in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/myproject.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name dev.myproject.com www.dev.myproject.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myproject_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myproject_error.log;

    location / { 
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/user/projects/myproject/media/;
    }

    location  /static/ {
        alias  /home/user/projects/myproject/static/;
    }
}
```

I must say that I think the real problem was to try to setup my DB configuration in the postactivate file of my virtualenv. Hope to help someone else.